# Nginx won't serve my JavaScript or images

Tags: nginx, server, nginx-config

Excuse me if I am being dumb or this is a duplicate question (I didn't find a solution that worked)

I am trying to use a static site with nginx, and my file structure is like this:

```
root
  img
    some image.jpg
    some image.jpg
  js
    some code.js
    some code.js
  css
    some code.css
    some code.css
```

and here is my config:

```
server {
    listen         80 default_server;
    listen         [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name    xilog.xyz www.xilog.xyz;
    root           /var/www/xilog.xyz/public_html;
    index          index.html index.htm index.php;
    autoindex      on;
}
```

If you visit the site you can see that it half works, with css working but when I try to access js and images that should be there, they don't appear (eg: xilog.xyz/img/logo.png) hence the loader which is stuck on and missing background.

Error log when I load site:

`2020/04/27 09:29:22 [error] 24648#24648: *6 open() "/var/www/xilog.xyz/public_html/cgi-bin/mainfunction.cgi" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 68.132.136.198, server: xilog.xyz, request: "GET /_img/portfolio/corkboard.png HTTP/1.1", host: "xilog.xyz"`

Last several access log lines:

```
141.101.99.65 - - [27/Apr/2020:11:52:21 +0000] "GET /img/logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 585687 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0" "122.167.110.18"
162.158.155.230 - - [27/Apr/2020:11:52:22 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 38078 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0" "122.167.110.18"
162.158.159.42 - - [27/Apr/2020:11:52:28 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12979 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0" "122.167.110.18"
162.158.158.221 - - [27/Apr/2020:11:52:28 +0000] "GET /js/portfolio.js HTTP/1.1" 200 803 "https://xilog.xyz/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0" "122.167.110.18"
162.158.158.115 - - [27/Apr/2020:11:52:28 +0000] "GET /js/easteregg.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1484 "https://xilog.xyz/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0" "122.167.110.18"
141.101.107.186 - - [27/Apr/2020:11:52:28 +0000] "GET /css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 16356 "https://xilog.xyz/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0" "122.167.110.18"
162.158.155.26 - - [27/Apr/2020:11:52:28 +0000] "GET /js/main.js HTTP/1.1" 200 4866 "https://xilog.xyz/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0" "122.167.110.18"
141.101.99.87 - - [27/Apr/2020:11:52:28 +0000] "GET /css/animations.css HTTP/1.1" 200 732 "https://xilog.xyz/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0" "122.167.110.18"
162.158.159.94 - - [27/Apr/2020:11:52:28 +0000] "GET /img/portfolio/corkboard.png HTTP/1.1" 200 4313 "https://xilog.xyz/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0" "122.167.110.18"
162.158.155.134 - - [27/Apr/2020:11:52:28 +0000] "GET /img/logo-white.png HTTP/1.1" 200 13837 "https://xilog.xyz/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0" "122.167.110.18"
141.101.107.162 - - [27/Apr/2020:11:52:28 +0000] "GET /css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 140942 "https://xilog.xyz/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0" "122.167.110.18"
162.158.154.31 - - [27/Apr/2020:11:52:29 +0000] "GET /img/portfolio/shift.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 525361 "https://xilog.xyz/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0" "122.167.110.18"
141.101.98.220 - - [27/Apr/2020:11:52:29 +0000] "GET /img/portfolio/extioh.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 362925 "https://xilog.xyz/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0" "122.167.110.18"
162.158.155.74 - - [27/Apr/2020:11:52:30 +0000] "GET /img/bg-med.png HTTP/1.1" 200 237622 "https://xilog.xyz/css/style.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0" "122.167.110.18"
162.158.159.142 - - [27/Apr/2020:11:53:07 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12979 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0" "122.167.110.18"
162.158.159.42 - - [27/Apr/2020:11:53:07 +0000] "GET /css/bootstrap.min.css.map HTTP/1.1" 200 562427 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0" "122.167.110.18"
162.158.159.42 - - [27/Apr/2020:11:53:13 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0" "122.167.110.18"
162.158.159.42 - - [27/Apr/2020:11:53:15 +0000] "GET /css/bootstrap.min.css.map HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0" "122.167.110.18"
162.158.159.42 - - [27/Apr/2020:11:53:18 +0000] "GET /css/bootstrap.min.css.map HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0" "122.167.110.18"
162.158.159.42 - - [27/Apr/2020:11:53:20 +0000] "GET /photography HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "https://xilog.xyz/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0" "122.167.110.18"
162.158.90.174 - - [27/Apr/2020:11:54:10 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 24 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SeznamBot/3.2; +http://napoveda.seznam.cz/en/seznambot-intro/)" "77.75.78.169"
141.101.96.180 - - [27/Apr/2020:11:54:12 +0000] "GET /_img/portfolio/corkboard.png HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SeznamBot/3.2; +http://napoveda.seznam.cz/en/seznambot-intro/)" "2a02:598:aaaa:2::8209"
162.158.119.7 - - [27/Apr/2020:11:54:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Safari/537.36" "2001:8f8:1329:dd06:e7c1:a5de:1c56:a3ee"
```

Comment: What do you see in the access log and the error log?

Answer (score 0):

Dang it, started working after waiting. I think it was a cache issue.